# Auctex block indent

Tags: indentation, emacs, editors, auctex

Is there a way to block indent whole paragraphs in `emacs` + `auctex`?  I'm thinking in that functionality in such editors as `WinEdt`.

I've search in different fora, and in the available documentation, but what I've found doesn't seem to work in `LaTeX` mode.

Comment: Do you mean indented in the LaTeX source or in the rendered document?

Comment: The source, of course....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my assessment based on the other comments etc. Based your screen shots you have the entire paragraph as one long line and you are using `visual-line-mode`.  That's perfectly fine except that `visual-line-mode` doesn't know how far to indent the wrapped lines.  To do that you have to use something like `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` which is available from the GNU ELPA.  Adding that to the appropriate hook should work.

The following isn't exactly how I invoke it, but I think it should work okay.

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean indent the source rather than indent the output,

There is `indent-region` (`C-M-\`) which will indent the region to what the mode thinks is the correct place relative to the previous line. If you want to force it you can give it a prefix argument so `C-u 9 C-M-\`  would indent the region to column 9.

---

failing that there's always

```
(defun foo()
(interactive)
(progn (mark-paragraph) (replace-string "\n" "\n     " nil (point) (mark))))
```

then M-x foo should indent the current para...

Comment: No, `indent-region` does nothing in my selected region.

Comment: My mode-line reads: `LaTeX/FMP Rel Fly vl Wrap`.

Comment: Without knowing what your selected region looks like, it's hard to know why `indent-region` isn't helping.  You might try tabbing the first line of the paragraph over manually, then using `M-q` (bound to `fill-paragraph`) to indent and fill it to that manually-selected indentation.

Comment: A typical paragraph wouldn't normally be indent by much. Does it move if you give the prefix arguent?

Comment: Only the first line of the paragraph gets indented. I was hoping the whole paragraph gets indented also (like a shift of the left margin).

Comment: This is how my buffer looks (it's the centre paragraph): http://i49.tinypic.com/2mpznz9.png

Comment: Chose the `classic` theme: http://i45.tinypic.com/j8dymg.png Could you please show me how it should look, in your editor?

Comment: @NVaughan Does indentation work if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: @N.N. No, it doesn't. I'm going to check this out in ubuntu, however.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's an interesting way of solving the issue at hand. However, it's a hard-wrap solution, and I was looking for a soft-wrap one. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: OK just saw the other answer. It would never occur to me to keep the paragraph as a single line:-)